# getting a last inserted varchar id which is an primary key

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple table ,which has to be inserted using different forms and all table have one id which is primary key and its varchar (NOT NULL),So i have one  class function named as id_calc($tbl,$id) where $tbl is a parameter with table name and $id is a field id .And each time  while inserting this function has to be called for id.

for example: If my id is "web1" ,next when i insert it shud give "web2","web3"...... i have tried with LAST_INSERT_ID() but  its not working.so i tried with fetching the max(id) and splitting the string and variable but is also giving some problem.so how can i do this.please help!!!

```
class first{
public function id_calc($tbl,$id)
    {
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT max($id) FROM $tbl where $id like '%web%'");
        if($sql)
        {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
             {
             $user=$row;
             $a=implode(" ",$user);

        }   
     $pattern = "/(\d+)/";
     $array = preg_split($pattern, $a, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
     $new[]=$array['0'];
     $new[]=$array['1']+1;
     $result=implode("",$new);
        return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

this function is called like

```
 public function insertreport1()
    {
    $obj=new first();
    $id=$obj->id_calc(tablename,idfield);
    //insert query
    }
```

this is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `report` (
  `inc_id` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `inc_status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `inc_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `inc_Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `inc_Age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `inc_Gender` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `inc_Mobile` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `inc_Address` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `inc_treatment` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inc_userid` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `inc_repTime` datetime NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`inc_id`),

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: alright, does the table have any autoincrement column? Note: `mysql_*` extension is deprecated, please refrain from using it.

Comment: then, you'll probably need to have a column for ordering. Either an autoincrement one or timestamp column which records the inserted time.

Comment: try using `new_id = 'web' + (string)((int)str_replace('web','',id)+1);` Also have  ordering in your where clause with limit 1 on some timestamp field which is indexed.

Comment: can any one tell me how to get the last inserted variable from the table ,it may by using the forms or may be by inserting into table  manually

Comment: @code-jaff can you please explain more specifically ....about autoincrementing timestamp column..

Comment: @shahmanthan9  i have tried with your solution  but it's not working.

Comment: @user092 would be possible that you can give few rows of your table?

Comment: @shahmanthan9 sorry , you want rows or the fields ?  and why you want that  ? .

Comment: @user092 i need rows, 2 or 3. This will help me to simulate it locally

Comment: @shahmanthan9 i have included my table structure..please see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71851/discussion-between-shahmanthan9-and-user092).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can do it this way..write the query as 
"SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING($id,4,12) AS UNSIGNED)) FROM $tbl WHERE $id LIKE '%web%'" 
and then increment the id as web+(max+1).

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo implementation would be

alter table definition

```
alter table `table` add column id int(11) not null auto_increment
```

change code

```
public function id_calc($tbl,$idcol) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM $tbl order by id desc limit 1");
    if($sql){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql));
        $id = isset($row['id']) ? $row['id'] + 1 : 1;
        return "{$idcol}{$id}";
    }
}
```

Hope this helps